# Microtype plus eplain and portuguese

Tags: babel, microtype, eplain

I am preparing a set of documents using eplain.
The text is in portuguese, so I'd like to have
proper hyphenation. At the same time,
I would like to use microtypography enhancements.
Here is my current attempt.

```latex
\input eplain

\input portuges.sty

% \beginpackages
%   \usepackage{letterspace}
% \endpackages

\begindocument


Oi! Um texto muito curto para testar se a quebra de palavras e a se
micro-tipografia funcionam. Pala\-vreado verboso, buscando
quebras-de-linha. Este documento seria processado
usando pdf\TeX. Um exemplo de palavra extremamente longa.

\bye
```

This produces the following result.

[image]

What I can't understand is why adding the commented-out lines
gives me the following error on `pdftex`-ing the document.

```
$ pdftex micro.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./micro.tex (/home/tassio/builds/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/eplain/eplain.tex
) (/home/tassio/builds/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/portuges.sty
(/home/tassio/builds/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-portuges/portuge
s.ldf (/home/tassio/builds/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/home/tassio/builds/texlive/2023/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def)
(/home/tassio/builds/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))))

(/home/tassio/builds/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@yargdef.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.192   \let\@hash@\relax

? h
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

?
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@yargdef.
<to be read again>
                   \the
l.197 ...  \edef\reserved@a{\reserved@a\@hash@\the
                                                  \@tempcntb}%
?
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@yargdef.
<to be read again>
                   \l@ngrel@x
l.200   \l@ngrel@x
                  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\reserved@a}
?
)
[. . . I'm omitting further messages . . . ]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this just an incompatibility between your package and `eplain`? The `eplain` manual lists `microtype` as “known not to work.”

Comment: By any chance, does the trick in the manual to redefine `\input` work?

Comment: by the time you have loaded `miniltx` really it would be simper to use latex

Comment: Oh, if I understand your comment @DavidCarlisle, does this means that `miniltx` included by ~~microtype~~ `eplain`? I somehow assumed (by havin seen the `\input` trick @Davislor mentioned) that parts of it had few dependencies.

Comment: microtype is not involved, the clash is babel (input by portuguese) and miniltx (input by `\beginpackages`

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: https://github.com/davidcarlisle/graphics-pln/commit/2ac07f2e8c63f30949ad1111bc877150948f78e3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed at source

https://github.com/davidcarlisle/graphics-pln/commit/2ac07f2e8c63f30949ad1111bc877150948f78e3

I'll arrange an update at ctan.

---

Two packages are defining `\@hash@`  just undefine it before the second one

```
\input eplain


\input portuges.sty

\expandafter\let\csname @hash@\endcsname\relax
 \beginpackages
   \usepackage{letterspace}
 \endpackages

\begindocument


Oi! Um texto muito curto para testar se a quebra de palavras e a se
micro-tipografia funcionam. Pala\-vreado verboso, buscando
quebras-de-linha. Este documento seria processado
usando pdf\TeX. Um exemplo de palavra extremamente longa.

\bye
```

Comment: These two packages are `miniltx` and `babel`, not `letterspace`. (A more minimal example would be: `\input eplain
\input english.sty
\beginpackages
\usepackage{graphics}
\endpackages
\bye`). So shouldn't this be fixed in babel and miniltx?

Comment: @Robert saying it should be fixed in babel and miniltx implies the issue is in those packages, it could be avoided with changes there but neither is I think tested with eplain at all or claims it works with eplain. You could I think reasonably say it's a failure of eplain to sufficiently emulate a normalised environment for loading latex code. In this specific case an alternative fix would be to use an updated version of `\newcommand` in miniltx which hasn't picked up on a change in latex made in 1999, the current version in latex doesn't use `\@hash@` at all.

Comment: babel [claims](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/using-babel-with-plain.html) to (somewhat) work with eplain; eplain in turn loads and "extends" miniltx for the package loading environment (eplain.pdf, p.35), so I assume the three packages are supposed to play nicely together, no?

Comment: @Robert well currently it's dying in miniltx (so from me) but while I'm aware eplain uses it, It's never tested in that setting (well not that it's tested at all really as it's not really changed since the 1990s) I suppose I could do something). But more generally I can see some point in using a small minimal plain format for quick jobs but a plain tex document with some rough hacks to allow loading a large chunk of latex just to avoid saying you use latex seems a somewhat low priority use case, to be honest. By the way (I think) there Javier means plain tex on etex by e-plain not eplain

Comment: @Robert see updated answer:-)

Answer (score 2):

If the reason of eplain usage is that your documents include plain TeX constructs, then there is another alternative: OpTeX.

```
\fontfam[lm]                   % Latin modern, Unicode alternative of CM
\ptlang                        % Portugese language
\load[mte]\enablemte           % MicroTypographic Extension
\margins/1 letter (1,1,1,1)in  % Paper format as in plain TeX

Oi! Um texto muito curto para testar se a quebra de palavras e a se
micro-tipografia funcionam. Palavreado verboso, buscando
quebras-de-linha. Este documento seria processado
usando \OpTeX. Um exemplo de palavra extremamente longa.

\bye
```

Note, that if your plain TeX document loads `miniltx` (as presented in your example), then the result is almost LaTeX.

Comment: Nice! I have indeed download OpTeX today to try it out as well =) As we're on the early stages of the project, it is not clear what the restrictions are going to be... One of the important things was to find a light format that we could maintain on the long run (years, potentially).